# Mutually exclusive checkable menu items?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menuitem

Given the following code:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Root" Header="Root">
    <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Item1" IsCheckable="True" Header="item1" />
    <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Item2" IsCheckable="True" Header="item2"/>
    <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Item3" IsCheckable="True" Header="item3"/>
</MenuItem>
```

In XAML, is there a way to create checkable menuitem's that are mutually exclusive?  Where is the user checks item2, item's 1 and 3 are automatically unchecked.

I can accomplish this in the code behind by monitoring the click events on the menu, determining which item was checked, and unchecking the other menuitems.  I'm thinking there is an easier way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Based upon the answers provided, I would say that there isn't an easier way that just doing it in the code behind with a foreach loop that unchecks all the items besides the newly checked item.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This may not be what you're looking for, but you could write an extension for the `MenuItem` class that allows you to use something like the `GroupName` property of the `RadioButton` class. I slightly modified [this](http://www.bradcunningham.net/2009/09/grouping-and-checkboxes-in-wpf.html) handy example for similarly extending `ToggleButton` controls and reworked it a little for your situation and came up with this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace WpfTest
{
     public class MenuItemExtensions : DependencyObject
     {
           public static Dictionary<MenuItem, String> ElementToGroupNames = new Dictionary<MenuItem, String>();

           public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupNameProperty =
               DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GroupName",
                                            typeof(String),
                                            typeof(MenuItemExtensions),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty, OnGroupNameChanged));

           public static void SetGroupName(MenuItem element, String value)
           {
                element.SetValue(GroupNameProperty, value);
           }

           public static String GetGroupName(MenuItem element)
           {
                return element.GetValue(GroupNameProperty).ToString();
           }

           private static void OnGroupNameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
           {
                //Add an entry to the group name collection
                var menuItem = d as MenuItem;

                if (menuItem != null)
                {
                     String newGroupName = e.NewValue.ToString();
                     String oldGroupName = e.OldValue.ToString();
                     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newGroupName))
                     {
                          //Removing the toggle button from grouping
                          RemoveCheckboxFromGrouping(menuItem);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          //Switching to a new group
                          if (newGroupName != oldGroupName)
                          {
                              if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oldGroupName))
                              {
                                   //Remove the old group mapping
                                   RemoveCheckboxFromGrouping(menuItem);
                              }
                              ElementToGroupNames.Add(menuItem, e.NewValue.ToString());
                               menuItem.Checked += MenuItemChecked;
                          }
                     }
                }
           }

           private static void RemoveCheckboxFromGrouping(MenuItem checkBox)
           {
                ElementToGroupNames.Remove(checkBox);
                checkBox.Checked -= MenuItemChecked;
           }


           static void MenuItemChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
                var menuItem = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
                foreach (var item in ElementToGroupNames)
                {
                     if (item.Key != menuItem && item.Value == GetGroupName(menuItem))
                     {
                          item.Key.IsChecked = false;
                     }
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

Then, in the XAML, you'd write:

```
        <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Root" Header="Root">
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Item1" YourNamespace:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="someGroup" IsCheckable="True" Header="item1" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Item2" YourNamespace:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="someGroup" IsCheckable="True" Header="item2"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Item3" YourNamespace:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="someGroup" IsCheckable="True" Header="item3"/>
        </MenuItem>
```

It's a bit of a pain, but it offers the perk of not forcing you to write any additional procedural code (aside from the extension class, of course) to implement it.

Credit goes to Brad Cunningham who authored the original ToggleButton solution.

Comment: [MK10's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18643222/2530736) shows how you can disable uncheck

Comment: So, is there's any method to get the checked MenuItem in a specific group? i.e `MenuItem item = MenuItemExtensions.GetCheckedItem("someGroup");`

Comment: Well, I've wrote this method if anyone is interested in using it: `
        public static MenuItem GetCheckedItem(string groupName)
        {
            foreach (var item in ElementToGroupNames)
            {
                MenuItem menuItem = item.Key;
                if (item.Value == groupName && menuItem.IsChecked)
                    return menuItem;
            }
            return null;
        }`

Answer (score 12):

Adding this at the bottom since I don't have the reputation yet...

As helpful as Patrick's answer is, it doesn't ensure that items cannot be unchecked. In order to do that, the Checked handler should be changed to a Click handler, and changed to the following:

```
static void MenuItemClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
    if (menuItem.IsChecked)
    {
        foreach (var item in ElementToGroupNames)
        {
            if (item.Key != menuItem && item.Value == GetGroupName(menuItem))
            {
                item.Key.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else // it's not possible for the user to deselect an item
    {
        menuItem.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you fire this event?

Answer (score 11):

You can also use a Behavior. Like this one:

```
<MenuItem Header="menu">

    <MenuItem x:Name="item1" Header="item1" IsCheckable="true" ></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem x:Name="item2" Header="item2" IsCheckable="true"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem x:Name="item3" Header="item3" IsCheckable="true" ></MenuItem>

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:MenuItemButtonGroupBehavior></local:MenuItemButtonGroupBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

</MenuItem>


public class MenuItemButtonGroupBehavior : Behavior<MenuItem>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        GetCheckableSubMenuItems(AssociatedObject)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(item => item.Click += OnClick);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        GetCheckableSubMenuItems(AssociatedObject)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(item => item.Click -= OnClick);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<MenuItem> GetCheckableSubMenuItems(ItemsControl menuItem)
    {
        var itemCollection = menuItem.Items;
        return itemCollection.OfType<MenuItem>().Where(menuItemCandidate => menuItemCandidate.IsCheckable);
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;

        if (!menuItem.IsChecked)
        {
            menuItem.IsChecked = true;
            return;
        }

        GetCheckableSubMenuItems(AssociatedObject)
            .Where(item => item != menuItem)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(item => item.IsChecked = false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution instead of the accepted answer as it was application scoped. I ended up having issues with multiple instance of the same control (registered name is shared).

Answer (score 7):

Since there is not a samilar answer, I post my solution here:

```
public class RadioMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        var ic = Parent as ItemsControl;
        if (null != ic)
        {
            var rmi = ic.Items.OfType<RadioMenuItem>().FirstOrDefault(i =>
                i.GroupName == GroupName && i.IsChecked);
            if (null != rmi) rmi.IsChecked = false;

            IsChecked = true;
        }
        base.OnClick();
    }
}
```

In XAML just use it as an usual MenuItem:

```
<MenuItem Header="OOO">
    <local:RadioMenuItem Header="111" GroupName="G1"/>
    <local:RadioMenuItem Header="222" GroupName="G1"/>
    <local:RadioMenuItem Header="333" GroupName="G1"/>
    <local:RadioMenuItem Header="444" GroupName="G1"/>
    <local:RadioMenuItem Header="555" GroupName="G1"/>
    <local:RadioMenuItem Header="666" GroupName="G1"/>
    <Separator/>
    <local:RadioMenuItem Header="111" GroupName="G2"/>
    <local:RadioMenuItem Header="222" GroupName="G2"/>
    <local:RadioMenuItem Header="333" GroupName="G2"/>
    <local:RadioMenuItem Header="444" GroupName="G2"/>
    <local:RadioMenuItem Header="555" GroupName="G2"/>
    <local:RadioMenuItem Header="666" GroupName="G2"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Quite simple and clean. And of course you can make the `GroupName` a dependency property by some additional codes, that's all the same as others.

BTW, if you do not like the check mark, you can change it to whatever you like:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    var p = GetTemplateChild("Glyph") as Path;
    if (null == p) return;
    var x = p.Width/2;
    var y = p.Height/2;
    var r = Math.Min(x, y) - 1;
    var e = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(x,y), r, r);
    // this is just a flattened dot, of course you can draw
    // something else, e.g. a star? ;)
    p.Data = e.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
}
```

If you used plenty of this `RadioMenuItem` in your program, there is another more efficient version shown below. The literal data is aquired from `e.GetFlattenedPathGeometry().ToString()` in previous code snippet.

```
private static readonly Geometry RadioDot = Geometry.Parse("M9,5.5L8.7,7.1 7.8,8.3 6.6,9.2L5,9.5L3.4,9.2 2.2,8.3 1.3,7.1L1,5.5L1.3,3.9 2.2,2.7 3.4,1.8L5,1.5L6.6,1.8 7.8,2.7 8.7,3.9L9,5.5z");
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    var p = GetTemplateChild("Glyph") as Path;
    if (null == p) return;
    p.Data = RadioDot;
}
```

And at last, if you plan to wrap it for use in your project, you should hide `IsCheckable` property from the base class, since the auto check machenism of `MenuItem` class will lead the radio check state mark a wrong behavior.

```
private new bool IsCheckable { get; }
```

Thus VS will give an error if a newbie try to compile XAML like this:

> // note that this is a wrong usage!
>
> `<local:RadioMenuItem Header="111" GroupName="G1" IsCheckable="True"/>`
>
> // note that this is a wrong usage!

Answer (score 6):

I just thought I would throw in my solution, since none of the answers met my needs. My full solution is here...

[WPF MenuItem as a RadioButton](http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/07/14/wpf-menuitem-as-a-radiobutton/)

However, the basic idea is to use ItemContainerStyle.

```
<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{DynamicResource RadioButtonResource}"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuItemWithRadioButtons_Click" />
    </Style>
</MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And the following event click should be added so that the RadioButton is checked when the MenuItem is clicked (otherwise you have to click exactly on the RadioButton):

```
private void MenuItemWithRadioButtons_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is MenuItem mi)
    {
        if (mi.Icon is RadioButton rb)
        {
            rb.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, though I kind of miss the tick when I set MenuItem.IsCheck=True.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this can be done easily by making every MenuItem a RadioButton. This can be done by Editing Template of MenuItem.

1. Right-Click the MenuItem in the Document-Outline left pane > EditTemplate > EditCopy. This will add the code for editing under Window.Resources.
2. Now, you have to do only two-changes which are very simple.

   [image: Mutually Exclusive MenuItems]a. Add the RadioButton with some Resources to hide its circle portion.

   b. Change BorderThickness = 0 for MenuItem Border part.

   These changes are shown below as comments, rest of the generated style should be used as is :

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
           <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuItemSelectionFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
               <GradientStop Color="#34C5EBFF" Offset="0"/>
               <GradientStop Color="#3481D8FF" Offset="1"/>
           </LinearGradientBrush>
           <Geometry x:Key="Checkmark">M 0,5.1 L 1.7,5.2 L 3.4,7.1 L 8,0.4 L 9.2,0 L 3.3,10.8 Z</Geometry>
           <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
               <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                   <Rectangle x:Name="Bg" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                   <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder" Margin="1" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2"/>
      <!-- Add RadioButton around the Grid 
      -->
                   <RadioButton Background="Transparent" GroupName="MENUITEM_GRP" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}">
                       <RadioButton.Resources>
                           <Style TargetType="Themes:BulletChrome">
                               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                           </Style>
                       </RadioButton.Resources>
      <!-- Add RadioButton Top part ends here
       -->
                       <Grid>
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                               <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="37"/>
                               <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
                           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

       <!-- Change border thickness to 0 
       -->    
                           <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#CDD3E6" BorderThickness="0" Background="#E6EFF4" CornerRadius="3" Height="22" Margin="1" Visibility="Hidden" Width="22">
                               <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="#0C12A1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="9"/>
                           </Border>
                           <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                           <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"/>
                       </Grid>
                   </RadioButton>
       <!-- RadioButton closed , thats it !
       -->
               </Grid>
             ...
       </Window.Resources>
   ```
3. Apply the Style ,

   ```
   <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="Open" Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}"
   ```

Comment: Where is MenuItemStyle1 defined?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple, **MVVM-based solution** that leverages a simple *IValueConverter* and *CommandParameter* per MenuItem.

No need to re-style any MenuItem as a different type of control. MenuItems will automatically be deselected when the bound value doesn't match the CommandParameter.

Bind to an int property (MenuSelection) on the DataContext (ViewModel).

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Root" Header="Root">
    <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Item1" IsCheckable="True" Header="item1" IsChecked="{Binding MenuSelection, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource MatchingIntToBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Item2" IsCheckable="True" Header="item2" IsChecked="{Binding MenuSelection, ConverterParameter=2, Converter={StaticResource MatchingIntToBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Item3" IsCheckable="True" Header="item3" IsChecked="{Binding MenuSelection, ConverterParameter=3, Converter={StaticResource MatchingIntToBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</MenuItem>
```

Define your value converter. This will check the bound value against the command parameter and vice versa.

```
public class MatchingIntToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var paramVal = parameter as string;
        var objVal = ((int)value).ToString();

        return paramVal == objVal;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            var i = System.Convert.ToInt32((parameter ?? "0") as string);

            return ((bool)value)
                ? System.Convert.ChangeType(i, targetType)
                : 0;
        }

        return 0; // Returning a zero provides a case where none of the menuitems appear checked
    }
}
```

Add your resource

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:MatchingIntToBooleanConverter x:Key="MatchingIntToBooleanConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is great! Instead of an int I used an enum in my view model.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a built-in way to do this in XAML, you will need to roll your own solution or get an existing solution if available.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this using a couple of lines of code:

First declare a variable:

```
MenuItem LastBrightnessMenuItem =null;
```

When we are considering a group of menuitems, there is a probability of using a single event handler. In this case we can use this logic:

```
    private void BrightnessMenuClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {

                    if (LastBrightnessMenuItem != null)
                    {
                        LastBrightnessMenuItem.IsChecked = false;
                    }

                    MenuItem m = sender as MenuItem;
                    LastBrightnessMenuItem = m;

                    //Handle the rest of the logic here


                }
```

Answer (score 2):

I find that I get mutually exclusive menu items when binding MenuItem.IsChecked to a variable.

But it has one quirk: If you click the selected menu item, it gets invalid, shown by the usual red rectangle. I solved it by adding a handler for MenuItem.Click that prevents unselecting by just setting IsChecked back to true.

The code... I'm binding to an enum type, so I use an enum converter that returns true if the bound property is equal to the supplied parameter. Here is the XAML:

```
    <MenuItem Header="Black"
              IsCheckable="True"
              IsChecked="{Binding SelectedColor, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}, ConverterParameter=Black}"
              Click="MenuItem_OnClickDisallowUnselect"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Red"
              IsCheckable="True"
              IsChecked="{Binding SelectedColor, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}, ConverterParameter=Red}"
              Click="MenuItem_OnClickDisallowUnselect"/>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
    private void MenuItem_OnClickDisallowUnselect(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
        if (menuItem == null) return;

        if (! menuItem.IsChecked)
        {
            menuItem.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Several years after i see this post with the keywords i wrote... i thought there was an easy solution, in wpf... Perhaps it's me, but i think it's a bit special to have a such massive arsenal for a so little thing as accepted solution. I don't even talk about the solution with 6likes i didn't understood where to click to have this options.

So perhaps it's really no elegant at all... But here a simple solution. What it do is simple.. a loop to all elements contained by the parent, to put it at false. The most of time people split this part from the others parts, of course it's only correct in this case.

```
private void MenuItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem itemChecked = (MenuItem)sender;
    MenuItem itemParent = (MenuItem)itemChecked.Parent;

    foreach (MenuItem item in itemParent.Items)
    {
        if (item == itemChecked)continue;

        item.IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

that's all and easy, xaml is a classic code with absolutaly nothing particular

```
<MenuItem Header="test">
    <MenuItem Header="1"  Click="MenuItem_Click_1" IsCheckable="True" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
    <MenuItem Header="2"  Click="MenuItem_Click_1" IsCheckable="True"  StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Of course you could have a need of the click method, it's not a problem, you can make a method that accept an object sender and each of your click method will use this method. It's old, it's ugly but for the while it works.
And i have some problems to imagine so much code line for a so little thing, it's probably me that have a problem with xaml, but it seems incredible to have to do this to obtains to just have only one  menuitem selected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another way – not easy by any stretch but it is MVVM compatible, bindable and highly unit testable.  If you have the freedom to add a Converter to your project and don’t mind a little garbage in the form of a new list of items every time the context menu opens, this works really well.  It meets the original question of how to provide a mutually exclusive set of checked items in a context menu.

I think if you want to extract all of this into a user control you could make it into a reusable library component to reuse across your application.
Components used are Type3.Xaml with a simple grid, one text block and the context menu.  Right-click anywhere in the grid to make the menu appear.

A value converter named AllValuesEqualToBooleanConverter is used to compare each menu item’s value to the current value of the group and show the checkmark next to the menu item that is currently selected.

A simple class that represent your menu choices is used for illustration.  The sample container uses Tuple with String and Integer properties that make is fairly easy to have a tightly coupled human readable snippet of text paired with a machine-friendly value.  You can use strings alone or String and an Enum to keep track of the Value for making decisions over what is current.
Type3VM.cs is the ViewModel that is assigned to the DataContext for Type3.Xaml.  However you contrive to assign your data context in your existing application framework, use the same mechanism here.  The application framework in use relies on INotifyPropertyChanged to communicate changed values to WPF and its binding goo.  If you have dependency properties you may need to tweak the code a little bit.

The drawback to this implementation, aside from the converter and its length, is that a garbage list is created every time the context menu is opened.  For single user applications this is probably ok but you should be aware of it.

The application uses an implementation of RelayCommand that is readily available from the Haacked website or any other ICommand-compatible helper class available in whatever framework you are using.

```
public class Type3VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<MenuData> menuData = new List<MenuData>(new[] 
        {
            new MenuData("Zero", 0),
            new MenuData("One", 1),
            new MenuData("Two", 2),
            new MenuData("Three", 3),
        });

        public IEnumerable<MenuData> MenuData { get { return menuData.ToList(); } }

        private int selected;
        public int Selected
        {
            get { return selected; }
            set { selected = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private ICommand contextMenuClickedCommand;
        public ICommand ContextMenuClickedCommand { get { return contextMenuClickedCommand; } }

        private void ContextMenuClickedAction(object clicked)
        {
            var data = clicked as MenuData;
            Selected = data.Item2;
            OnPropertyChanged("MenuData");
        }

        public Type3VM()
        {
            contextMenuClickedCommand = new RelayCommand(ContextMenuClickedAction);
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class MenuData : Tuple<String, int>
    {
        public MenuData(String DisplayValue, int value) : base(DisplayValue, value) { }
    }

<UserControl x:Class="SampleApp.Views.Type3"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Views"
             xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Converters"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:SampleApp.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModels:Type3VM}"
             >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Converters:AllValuesEqualToBooleanConverter x:Key="IsCheckedVisibilityConverter" EqualValue="True" NotEqualValue="False" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuData, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem" >
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Item1}" />
                        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsCheckedVisibilityConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext.Selected" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Views:Type3}}"  />
                                    <Binding Path="Item2" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ContextMenuClickedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Views:Type3}}}" />
                        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding .}" />
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions><RowDefinition Height="*" /></Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions><ColumnDefinition Width="*" /></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="30" Text="Right Click For Menu" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

public class AreAllValuesEqualConverter<T> : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public T EqualValue { get; set; }
    public T NotEqualValue { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        T returnValue;

        if (values.Length < 2)
        {
            returnValue = EqualValue;
        }

        // Need to use .Equals() instead of == so that string comparison works, but must check for null first.
        else if (values[0] == null)
        {
            returnValue = (values.All(v => v == null)) ? EqualValue : NotEqualValue;
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue = (values.All(v => values[0].Equals(v))) ? EqualValue : NotEqualValue;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(Boolean))]
public class AllValuesEqualToBooleanConverter : AreAllValuesEqualConverter<Boolean>
{ }
```

Answer (score 1):

A small addition to the @Patrick answer.

As @MK10 mentioned, this solution allows user to deselect all items in a group. But the changes he suggested doesn't work for me now. Maybe, the WPF model was changed since that time, but now `Checked` event doesn't fired when an item is unchecked.

To avoid it, I would suggest to process the `Unchecked` event for `MenuItem`.

I changed these procedures:

```
        private static void OnGroupNameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(d is MenuItem menuItem))
                return;

            var newGroupName = e.NewValue.ToString();
            var oldGroupName = e.OldValue.ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newGroupName))
            {
                RemoveCheckboxFromGrouping(menuItem);
            }
            else
            {
                if (newGroupName != oldGroupName)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldGroupName))
                    {
                        RemoveCheckboxFromGrouping(menuItem);
                    }
                    ElementToGroupNames.Add(menuItem, e.NewValue.ToString());
                    menuItem.Checked += MenuItemChecked;
                    menuItem.Unchecked += MenuItemUnchecked; // <-- ADDED
                }
            }
        }

        private static void RemoveCheckboxFromGrouping(MenuItem checkBox)
        {
            ElementToGroupNames.Remove(checkBox);
            checkBox.Checked -= MenuItemChecked;
            checkBox.Unchecked -= MenuItemUnchecked;   // <-- ADDED
        }
```

and added the next handler:

```
    private static void MenuItemUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.OriginalSource is MenuItem menuItem))
            return;

        var isAnyItemChecked = ElementToGroupNames.Any(item => item.Value == GetGroupName(menuItem) && item.Key.IsChecked);
        if (!isAnyItemChecked)
            menuItem.IsChecked = true;
    }
```

Now the checked item remains checked when user clicks it second time.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can hook both check and uncheck event for the MenuItem and inside the event you can call a common method like below:

        private void MenuItem_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.UpdateCheckeditem(sender as MenuItem);
        }

        private void MenuItem_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.UpdateCheckeditem(sender as MenuItem);
        }

        private void UpdateCheckedstatus(MenuItem item)
        {
             MenuItem itemChecked = (MenuItem)sender;
            MenuItem itemParent = (MenuItem)itemChecked.Parent;

            foreach (MenuItem item in itemParent.Items)
            {

                if (item != itemChecked && item.IsChecked)
                {
                    item.IsChecked = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

I think this will give you the expected behavior.
```

Comment: Quick and useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a Template for MenuItem which will contain a RadioButton with a GroupName set to some value.
You can also change the template for the RadioButtons to look like the MenuItem's default check glyph (which can be easily extracted with Expression Blend).

That's it!

Comment: I'm with you on this one.  So many people are over-engineering the heck out of this....  It's exactly as simple as you've described it and I've done it plenty of times before, even as elaborate as a drawer menu panel.  WPF allows for some insane styling, why not take advantage of that.

Comment: It's not that simple. The answers by Rhyous and AnjumSKhan work on the details of this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <ListBox BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Header="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.Items>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Test" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Test2" />
                    </ListBox.Items>
                </ListBox>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

It has some weird side effect visually (you'll see when you use it), but it works nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that uses RoutedUICommands, a public enum property, and DataTriggers. This is a pretty verbose solution. I unfortunately don't see any way of making the Style.Triggers smaller, because I don't know how to just say that the Binding Value is the only thing different? (BTW, for MVVMers this is a terrible example. I put everything in the MainWindow class just to keep things simple.)

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MutuallyExclusiveMenuItems.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MutuallyExclusiveMenuItems"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static view:MainWindow.MenuItem1Cmd}" 
        CanExecute="CanExecute"
        Executed="MenuItem1Execute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static view:MainWindow.MenuItem2Cmd}" 
        CanExecute="CanExecute"
        Executed="MenuItem2Execute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static view:MainWindow.MenuItem3Cmd}" 
        CanExecute="CanExecute"
        Executed="MenuItem3Execute" />
  </Window.CommandBindings>

  <Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{x:Static view:MainWindow.MenuItem1Cmd}" Gesture="Ctrl+1"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{x:Static view:MainWindow.MenuItem2Cmd}" Gesture="Ctrl+2"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{x:Static view:MainWindow.MenuItem3Cmd}" Gesture="Ctrl+3"/>
  </Window.InputBindings>

  <DockPanel>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="_Root">
          <MenuItem Command="{x:Static view:MainWindow.MenuItem1Cmd}" 
                    InputGestureText="Ctrl+1">
            <MenuItem.Style>
              <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentMenuItem, Mode=OneWay}" 
                               Value="{x:Static view:MainWindow+CurrentItemEnum.EnumItem1}">
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
            </MenuItem.Style>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem Command="{x:Static view:MainWindow.MenuItem2Cmd}"
                    InputGestureText="Ctrl+2">
            <MenuItem.Style>
              <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentMenuItem, Mode=OneWay}" 
                               Value="{x:Static view:MainWindow+CurrentItemEnum.EnumItem2}">
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
            </MenuItem.Style>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem Command="{x:Static view:MainWindow.MenuItem3Cmd}"
                    InputGestureText="Ctrl+3">
            <MenuItem.Style>
              <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentMenuItem, Mode=OneWay}" 
                               Value="{x:Static view:MainWindow+CurrentItemEnum.EnumItem3}">
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
            </MenuItem.Style>
          </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MutuallyExclusiveMenuItems
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
    }

    #region Enum Property
    public enum CurrentItemEnum { EnumItem1, EnumItem2, EnumItem3 };

    private CurrentItemEnum _currentMenuItem;
    public CurrentItemEnum CurrentMenuItem
    {
      get { return _currentMenuItem; }
      set
      {
        _currentMenuItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentMenuItem");
      }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion Enum Property

    #region Commands
    public static RoutedUICommand MenuItem1Cmd = 
      new RoutedUICommand("Item_1", "Item1cmd", typeof(MainWindow));
    public void MenuItem1Execute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      CurrentMenuItem = CurrentItemEnum.EnumItem1;
    }
    public static RoutedUICommand MenuItem2Cmd = 
      new RoutedUICommand("Item_2", "Item2cmd", typeof(MainWindow));
    public void MenuItem2Execute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      CurrentMenuItem = CurrentItemEnum.EnumItem2;
    }
    public static RoutedUICommand MenuItem3Cmd = 
      new RoutedUICommand("Item_3", "Item3cmd", typeof(MainWindow));
    public void MenuItem3Execute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      CurrentMenuItem = CurrentItemEnum.EnumItem3;
    }
    public void CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      e.CanExecute = true;
    }
    #endregion Commands
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom control that i've created for this purpose.
It handles correctly checking, unchecking, clicks events and group name changes.

If you want you can override the style of the menu item and change the checkmark to a radiomark, but is not necessary:

```
public class RadioMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    private bool abortCheckChange = false;

    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string GroupName
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(GroupNameProperty);
        set => SetValue(GroupNameProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(GroupName), typeof(string), typeof(RadioMenuItem),
            new PropertyMetadata("", (d, e) => ((RadioMenuItem)d).OnGroupNameChanged((string)e.OldValue, (string)e.NewValue)));


    static RadioMenuItem()
    {
        IsCheckedProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(RadioMenuItem),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, (d, o) => ((RadioMenuItem)d).abortCheckChange ? d.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty) : o));
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new RadioMenuItem();
    }

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        //This will handle correctly the click, but prevents the unchecking.
        //So the menu item acts that is correctly clicked (e.g. the menu disappears
        //but the user can only check, not uncheck the item.
        if (IsCheckable && IsChecked) abortCheckChange = true;
        base.OnClick();
        abortCheckChange = false;
    }

    protected override void OnChecked(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnChecked(e);
        //If the menu item is checked, other items of the same group will be unchecked.
        if (IsChecked) UncheckOtherGroupItems();
    }

    protected virtual void OnGroupNameChanged(string oldGroupName, string newGroupName)
    {
        //If the menu item enters on another group and is checked, other items will be unchecked.
        if (IsChecked) UncheckOtherGroupItems();
    }

    private void UncheckOtherGroupItems()
    {
        if (IsCheckable)
        {
            IEnumerable<RadioMenuItem> radioItems = Parent is ItemsControl parent ? parent.Items.OfType<RadioMenuItem>()
                .Where((item) => item.IsCheckable && (item.DataContext == parent.DataContext || item.DataContext != DataContext)) : null;

            if (radioItems != null)
            {
                foreach (RadioMenuItem item in radioItems)
                {
                    if (item != this && item.GroupName == GroupName)
                    {
                        //This will uncheck all other items on the same group.
                        item.IsChecked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
<Grid Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="125" Margin="139,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="Normal check 1"/>
            <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="Normal check 2"/>
            <Separator/>
            <local:RadioMenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="Radio check 1" GroupName="Group1"/>
            <local:RadioMenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="Radio check 2" GroupName="Group1"/>
            <local:RadioMenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="Radio check 3" GroupName="Group1"/>
            <Separator/>
            <local:RadioMenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="Radio check 4" GroupName="Group2"/>
            <local:RadioMenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="Radio check 5" GroupName="Group2"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and correct way to implement mutually exclusive toolstrip menu item is;

```
private void ChangecheckedItemsOnDropdownItemsClick(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
 //get the currently checked item
 ToolStripMenuItem itemChecked = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

 // loop through the dropdown items for the main ToolStrip item
 foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in NameofParentToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems)
 {
 // if the current item is same as checked item, continue
 if (item == itemChecked) continue;
  // else uncheck the item
 else
  item.Checked = false;
 }
}
```

Please replace NameofParentToolStripMenuItem with the menuitem where you want to have this property.

Comment: "Please help me understand if that is correct" -  is this query to the question author? Their question is some 13 years old, so they might not be able to remember the context of what they were doing.

Comment: In general, answers should be definitive - i.e. they should answer the question and refrain from supplementary/arising questions. If you have a new question for a general audience that is best posted as a new question.

Comment: Since there has been no answer to my enquiry above (despite the user signing in) I am voting as NAA.