# Menu item with exactly one checked value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menu, menuitem

I want to have in my application a context menu "DefaultPrinter" which has some binded childs (another MenuItems) representing printer's names. Each child has a property IsCheckable set to true.

```
<MenuItem Header="DefaultPrinter" ItemsSource="{Binding AllPrinters}">
     <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
              <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
          </Style>
     </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

However, of course I want allow only one printer to be checked (this code doesn't suport that). I looked for solution in the Internet, but didn't find anything helpful.
The problem is that `MenuItem` derieves from `ItemsControl` and since that it has no concept of items selection (like `Selector`). I can try to write my own selection, but first, I would like to know is there better and simplier solution for achieving that goal.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979753/how-do-you-add-radio-buttons-to-menu-items AND  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652688/mutually-exclusive-checkable-menu-items

Answer (score 1):

Could abuse a hidden `RadioButton`:

```
<MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Printers"
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
```