# How to Uncheck Menuitem isCheked property in MenuItemClick event

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I am able to check the menuitem but not able to uncheck and more over it showing previous check in the menuitem. Once I click on the another menuitem it doesn't uncheck the previous menuitem. I'm adding menuitem from code.

```
  private void OnMenuItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                RoutedEventArgs args = e as RoutedEventArgs;
                MenuItem item = args.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
                string header = item.Header.ToString();
                if (header == "B1")
                {
                    btnMenu.Content = header;
                    item.IsChecked=true;
                }
                else if (header == "A1")
                {
                    btnMenu.Content = header;
                    item.IsChecked=true;
                }

            }
```

I am applying the same  menuitems and its event handler for 4 buttons.So that if i select one menuitem for first button it will show check on menuitem,the checked menu item show appear when i click on second button.how can i achieve this?..Any suggestion.

EDIT:xaml

```
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="11" Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                                    <Button  Name="btnPhone" Content="Mobile" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0 0 12 0" Width="85" Click="OnbtnPhoneClick"></Button>
                                                                          <Button   HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="ddBtnPhone" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25"  Click="OnddBtnPhoneClick"  >
                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <Path x:Name="btnArrow1" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Fill="#FF527DB5" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "/>
                                        </Button.Content>
                                        <Button.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu x:Name="cmPhone">

                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </Button.ContextMenu>
                                    </Button>


                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="12" Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                                    <Button  Name="btnHome" Content="Business" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,0,12,5" Width="85" Click="OnbtnHomeClick" />
                                    <!--<extToolkit:DropDownButton x:Name="ddBtnHome" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 30 0" Height="20"/>-->
                                    <Button   HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="ddBtnHome" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="25"  Click="OnddBtnHomeClick" Margin="0,0,0,5"  >
                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <Path x:Name="btnArrow2" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Fill="#FF527DB5" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "/>
                                        </Button.Content>
                                        <Button.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu Name="cmHome">

                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </Button.ContextMenu>
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="13" Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                                    <Button  Name="btnMobile" Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0 0 12 0" Width="85" Click="OnbtnMobileClick"></Button>
                                    <!--<extToolkit:DropDownButton x:Name="ddBtnMobile" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 30 0" Height="20"/>-->
                                    <Button   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ddBtnMobile" Width="25" Click="OnddBtnMobileClick"  Margin="0,0,0,5"  >
                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <Path x:Name="btnArrow3" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Fill="#FF527DB5" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "/>
                                        </Button.Content>
                                        <Button.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu Name="cmMobile">

                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </Button.ContextMenu>
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="14" Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                                    <Button  Name="btnFAX" Content="Business FAX" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0 0 12 0" Width="85" Click="OnbtnFAXClick"></Button>
                                    <!--<extToolkit:DropDownButton x:Name="ddBtnFAX" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 30 0" Height="20"/>-->
                                    <Button   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ddBtnFAX" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="25" Click="OnddBtnFAXClick"  Margin="0,0,0,5"  >
                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <Path x:Name="btnArrow4" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Fill="#FF527DB5" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "/>
                                        </Button.Content>
                                        <Button.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu Name="cmFAX">

                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </Button.ContextMenu>
                                    </Button>

                                </StackPanel>
```

this is how i am adding menuitems for each contextMenu.

```
  private void AddMenuItems(ContextMenu cMenu, Button btnName)
    {
        if (cMenu.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            mnItem = new MenuItem();
            mnItem.Header = "B1";
            cMenu.Items.Add(mnItem);
            mnItem = new MenuItem();
            mnItem.Header = "A1";
            cMenu.Items.Add(mnItem);
            mnItem = new MenuItem();
            mnItem.Header = "B2";
            cMenu.Items.Add(mnItem);
            mnItem = new MenuItem();
            mnItem.Header = "A2";
            cMenu.Items.Add(mnItem);

            cMenu.AddHandler(MenuItem.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnMenuItemClick));
            cMenu.AddHandler(MenuItem.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseButtonUpEventClick));
            btnCommon = btnName;
        }
```

Comment: can you please show the xaml.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand what it is you want. But if you want MenuItems which are checked mutually exclusive you should check this post:
[Mutually exclusive checkable menu items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652688/mutually-exclusive-checkable-menu-items)