# How to change the MenuItem Header according to the value selected in its submenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menu, menuitem

```
<Window x:Class="MenuKinect.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>


        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">

            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                      <Border x:Name="Border" 
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0" MinWidth="17" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuTextColumnGroup"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3" Width="14"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!-- ContentPresenter to show an Icon if needed -->
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon"/>
                                <!-- Glyph is a checkmark if needed for a checkable menu -->
                                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="GlyphPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Path x:Name="GlyphPanelpath" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,2 L0,4.8 L2.5,7.4 L7.1,2.8 L7.1,0 L2.5,4.6 z" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <!-- Content for the menu text etc -->
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" 
Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
x:Name="HeaderHost" 
RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
ContentSource="Header"/>
                                <!-- Content for the menu IGT -->
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" 
Margin="8,1,8,1" 
x:Name="IGTHost" 
ContentSource="InputGestureText" 
VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <!-- Arrow drawn path which points to the next level of the menu -->
                                <Grid Grid.Column="3" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="ArrowPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Path x:Name="ArrowPanelPath" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,0 L0,8 L4,4 z"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <!-- The Popup is the body of the menu which expands down or across depending on the level of the item -->
                                <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" x:Name="SubMenuPopup" Focusable="false" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}">
                                    <!--<Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2,2,2,2">-->
                                        <Grid x:Name="SubMenu" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                                            <!-- StackPanel holds children of the menu. This is set by IsItemsHost=True -->
                                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    <!--</Border>-->
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <!-- These triggers re-configure the four arrangements of MenuItem to show different levels of menu via Role -->
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!-- Role = TopLevelHeader : this is the root menu item in a menu; the Popup expands down -->
                            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom" TargetName="SubMenuPopup"/>
                                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" TargetName="Col0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" TargetName="Col3"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="GlyphPanel"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="IGTHost"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!-- Role = TopLevelItem :  this is a child menu item from the top level without any child items-->
                            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!-- Role = SubMenuHeader : this is a child menu item which does not have children -->
                            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,0,2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!-- Role = SubMenuItem : this is a child menu item which has children-->
                            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,0,2"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None" TargetName="SubMenuPopup"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!-- If no Icon is present the we collapse the Icon Content -->
                            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!-- The GlyphPanel contains the CheckMark -->
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="GlyphPanel"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!-- Using the system colors for the Menu Highlight and IsEnabled-->
                            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" TargetName="Border"/>-->
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />-->
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFa4ddfa"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <Menu Height="23" Name="menu1" Width="171" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF004165">

            <!--<Menu.BitmapEffect>

                <DropShadowBitmapEffect />

            </Menu.BitmapEffect>-->

            <MenuItem Header="Settings">
                <MenuItem x:Name="headerLogoutTime" Header="LogOut Time" Background="#FF004165" Click="headerLogoutTime_Click">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="header10Min" Header="10 Min"  Background="#FF004165" ></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="header20Min" Header="20 Min"  Background="#FF004165" ></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="header30Min" Header="30 Min"  Background="#FF004165" ></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="header40Min" Header="40 Min"  Background="#FF004165" ></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="header50Min" Header="50 Min"  Background="#FF004165" ></MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem Header="LogOut" Background="#FF004165"></MenuItem>

            </MenuItem>

        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have almost made my code according to the given picture,i have used menu and submenu,now i want like in the above picture,that when i select any item of submenu i.e,10 or 20 or 30,it should append with the header logouttime and should be displayed to us when we hover on any item,how to do this?i want to do exactly what is displayed in the image..please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

**`XAML`**

```
<Grid>       
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyMenuItem" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}"
               TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">

            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="headerLogoutTime_Click" />
            <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="headerMin_MouseEnter" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF004165" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Menu Height="23" Name="menu1" Width="171" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF004165">
        <MenuItem Header="Settings">
            <MenuItem x:Name="headerLogoutTime"
                      Header="LogOut Time: 00 Min" 
                      Background="#FF004165">

                <MenuItem x:Name="header10Min" 
                          Header="10 Min"
                          Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" />

                <MenuItem x:Name="header20Min"
                          Header="20 Min"
                          Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" />

                <MenuItem x:Name="header30Min"
                          Header="30 Min" 
                          Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" />

                <MenuItem x:Name="header40Min"
                          Header="40 Min" 
                          Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" />

                <MenuItem x:Name="header50Min" 
                          Header="50 Min"
                          Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" />
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem Header="LogOut" Background="#FF004165" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

**`Code-behind`**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void headerLogoutTime_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetMenuItemHeader(sender as MenuItem);
    }

    private void headerMin_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SetMenuItemHeader(sender as MenuItem);
    }

    private void SetMenuItemHeader(MenuItem menuItem) 
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (menuItem != null)
        {
            headerLogoutTime.Header = "";
            headerLogoutTime.Header = sb.Append("LogOut Time: ").Append(headerLogoutTime.Header).Append(menuItem.Header);
        }
    }
}
```

**`Clarification`**

In `MyMenuItem` Style we define a Click and MouseEnter handlers for all MenuItems, what contains in `headerLogoutTime`, here it also we set the Background color.

In `headerLogoutTime_Click` and in `headerMin_MouseEnter` handlers, with help of [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) setting new value for MenuItem Header. Class `StringBuilder` chosen to enhance performance for working with strings.

**`Edit: add line as separator`**

To display the line, as in your picture, use [`Separator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.separator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control with Style:

```
<Style x:Key="SeparatorStyleKey" 
        TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">

    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="1" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                           Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                           Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And use like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Settings">
    <MenuItem x:Name="headerLogoutTime"
                Header="LogOut Time: 00 Min" 
                Background="#FF004165">

        <MenuItem x:Name="header10Min" 
                    Header="10 Min"
                    Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" />

        <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyleKey}" />

        <MenuItem x:Name="header20Min"
                    Header="20 Min"
                    Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" />

        <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyleKey}" />

        <MenuItem x:Name="header30Min"
                    Header="30 Min" 
                    Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" />

        <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyleKey}" />

        <MenuItem x:Name="header40Min"
                    Header="40 Min" 
                    Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" />

        <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyleKey}" />

        <MenuItem x:Name="header50Min" 
                    Header="50 Min"
                    Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" />
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem Header="LogOut" Background="#FF004165" />
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Anatoliy Nikolaev thanks for the answer,i also want to add white thin lines after every menuitem like those shown in image,how to add these lines??

Comment: Anatoliy Nikolaev i have added this code in my every menu item-<MenuItem x:Name="header10Min" Header="10 Min"  Background="#FF004165"  Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" IsCheckable="True" MenuKinect:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="LogOutTimeGroup"  ></MenuItem>,so that only one item from menu can be checked at a time,and i have added this class-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652688/mutually-exclusive-checkable-menu-items(posted by patrick),but it is giving error-MenuKinect is an undeclared prefix..how to resolve this??

Comment: @NikitaGupta: Maybe you will create a new question, and you will not have to ask me in the comments? I answered your main question, and the question of a comment (about Separator).